# How do I use IntelliJ with Subversion, Git and "git-svn"

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-svn

How do I use IntelliJ with Subversion, Git and "git-svn".

My firm is using subversion for the main    repository but I like to use git so I use the command line and issue the following commands

git-svn clone -s http://example.com/my_subversion_repo local_dir

but at the end I have to issue a git-svn dcommit can this be done from within IntelliJ

git-svn dcommit

Comment: It's [not supported](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-26427) in IDEA.

Comment: I've used SmartGit for a couple years and love it.  I tried doing git workflow in IntelliJ but went back to SmartGit.  I haven't used it with svn yet, but this might interest you: http://www.syntevo.com/smartgithg/svn-index

Answer (score 4):

You can use built-in IntelliJ Git support with [SubGit](http://subgit.com/).

There are different options:

1. If you have administrator access to Subversion repository, you can install SubGit 1.0 into this repository and enable Git access to your SVN repository. This way you can work with created Git repository and SubGit will synchronize all the changes with SVN counterpart.
2. You can also use SubGit 2.0 (EAP stage at the moment) and synchronize local Git repository with remote SVN repository. So you can keep working with SubGit-enabled local Git repository and all the changes will be replicated to SVN repository.

For more information please refer to [SubGit documentation](http://subgit.com/documentation/) and to [comparison with git-svn](http://subgit.com/documentation/gitsvn.html).

Disclaimer: I'm one of SubGit developers; SubGit is a commercial software with some free options; SubGit 2.0 EAP builds are free to use.

Answer (score 1):

I confirmed with IntelliJ it can't be done right now..

Comment: Thats a pitty, hope this will change.

Answer (score 1):

I use PyCharm (which is based on IntelliJ) and I worked around this by setting up a custom command under "External Tools" as follows:

```
Name:        dcommit
Program:     git
Arguments:   svn dcommit
Working Dir: $ProjectFileDir$
```

You can then dcommit in one of the following ways:

- Select the `Tools > External Tools > dcommit` menu option
- Use the `Ctrl+Shift+A` (Find Action...) popup to execute 'dcommit'
- Assign a keyboard shortcut in your keymap for even easier execution

Answer (score 0):

It could be a reality in short time: https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/pull/725

Still you need to clone from command line, but after that is merged, other features will be implemented (dcommit, clone, tag)